# Importar dados do access para o excel com base em critérios

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho uma tabela no access e já consigo até puxar os dados dela para uma planilha do excel (consigo fazer isso utilizando o código abaixo), porém gostaria de poder puxar apenas alguns dados (com base em critérios, tipo um filtro avançado do excel, só que realizado entre o excel e o access). Ressaltando que a tabela no access tem tipo 15 colunas e o meu filtro seria só com umas 5 colunas.

Código que já tenho e que funciona bem (o problema é que puxa toda a tabela do access):

```
Sub BuscaDoAccess()

    Dim MDB As New Connection
    Dim RS As New Recordset
    Dim FD As ADODB.Field
    Dim SQL As String

    MDB.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data 
    Source=C:\Users\Clebson\Desktop\BD.mdb"

    SQL = "select * from HistoricoGeral"
    COL = 2

    RS.Open SQL, MDB

    If Not RS.EOF Then
        For Each FD In RS.Fields
            Sheets("Planilha1").Cells(1, COL).Value = FD.Name
            COL = COL + 1
        Next FD

        COL = 2
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1").Cells(2, COL).CopyFromRecordset RS
    End If

    RS.Close
    MDB.Close

    Set MDB = Nothing
    Set RS = Nothing
    Set FD = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Tente colocar alguma condição no seu select. Select * from HistoricoGeral WHERE 'Nome de alguma coluna' = 'algum dado que existe nela'                                                 

Esse site pode te ajudar, http://www.macoratti.net/12/10/c_mxls1.htm

Comment: Opa. Para um critério posto de forma manual já foi. Você saberia como faço para por mais critérios? sendo que terei 5 colunas para tal filtro, mais o utilizador poderá usar só uma ou duas.